# composer.json error: "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I made a composer.json script.

When I run `sudo composer install`, I get this error:

```
[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]               
"./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON  
Parse error on line 1:                         
"repositories": [    {        "t               
--------------^                                
Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

Here is the JSON:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"package",
        "package": {
          "name": "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core",
          "version":"development",
          "source": {
              "url": "https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Core.git",
              "type": "git",
              "reference":"development"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core": "development"
}
```

How can I get a better description of how this JSON is wrong?

Comment: Let's ask the other way around: what makes you think that the posted JSON **is** valid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your JSON is bad, Paste your JSON into this website: http://jsonlint.com/

It returns the error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
"repositories": [  
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

If you surround your entire JSON with a `{`  at the beginning and `}` at very end, the invalid JSON becomes valid.

Answer (score 1):

I'll share my $0.02. More than once I have faced this problem because of GIT conflicts. So sometimes your `composer.lock` will have the following conflict indications:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
"funding": [
{
    "url": "https://github.com/jenssegers",
    "type": "github"
},
{
    "url": "https://tidelift.com/funding/github/packagist/jenssegers/agent",
    "type": "tidelift"
}
],
=======
>>>>>>> a19a747062fe0ace379f410ad94e27463eee436c
```

This stuff got injected when a git conflict was not resolved properly, thereby making the lock file invalid. To fix this problem, simply remove the conflicting sections of your lock file by comparing it with the file history.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use it like this.

Try with this it will helps you to recover your error.

```
{
   "repositories": [{
     "type": "package",
     "package": {
        "name": "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core",
        "version": "development",
        "source": {
            "url": "https://github.com/AdamKyle/Aisis-Core.git",
            "type": "git",
            "reference": "development"
        }
    }
  }],
  "require": {
      "AdamKyle/Aisis-Core": "development"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add `"["` and `"]"` in the starting and ending of the file.

Comment: Could you share some explanation about this? All files I've seen use `{` at the beginning